# Tricking the file system to mount a LINK2SD drive as mnt/extsd

Tags: root-access, mount, link2sd, ext4

I've got a device that is using the brilliant LINK2SD to expand the system memory onto the SD......all good.

As part of the implementation, the app mounts the two SD card partitions as:

1. FAT32 `/mnt/extsd/179_49`

and

2. EXT4 `/mnt/extsd/179_50`

Of course a regular FAT32 SD card mounts as `/mnt/extsd` so the problem then presents itself with some apps that are hard coded to look for `/mnt/extsd` for SD storage.....apps like Camera fail with errors similar to can't find SD card etc.

My question is how can I mount/trick the system to mount the FAT32 partition `/mnt/extsd/179_49` as `/mnt/extsd` ???

I've got root access, terminal etc.

Any ideas folk ?

Cheers

David

Comment: What Android Version is your device? Mention it in the question, because if it's JellyBean or below, you can do that by simply editing the `vold.fstab`, or for KitKat and above, I'm afraid you'll need to edit the ramdisk in boot.img

Answer (score 0):

```
/mnt/extsd/179_49 
/mnt/extsd/179_50
/mnt/extsd
```

some type of round-robin.

Your going to have to move your data in '49 & '50 to someother directories. mkdir /sdcard/externalData

```
rmdir '49
rmdir '50
rmdir extsd

cd mnt
ln -s /sdcard/externalData extsd

cd extsd
ln -s /sdcard/new49 179_49 

ln -s /sdcard/new50 179_50
```

Whether this will work will depends on the capabilities of ln.  This would work in normal unix  / linux boxes.

R

Comment: It's not that easy in Android even if we have root access.. @historystamp